# What's the css for setting a form select element's width and horizontal position?

Tags: html, css

Should width be treated instead with an html attribute?

I know about left and right margin for setting horizontal position, but the validation messages from my javascript are being messed up when using

```
margenleft{
             margin-left:120px;
        }
```

on a different resolution, how can I do this relatively? I want the select elements to be centrally placed.

Comment: We need more context. A short, self-containing and executable example would be more than helpful.

Comment: `select` elements are considered inline-elements by default, so if you apply a `text-align: center;` to their parent element they should be centered. And +1 to BalusC for requesting more context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change the `select` to display: block, you can centre and set its width with the following CSS:

```
select {
   /* Set as display block and auto left/right margins to centre */ 
   display: block;
   margin: 0 auto;

   /* Set select's width */
   width: 200px;       
}
```

And for your viewing pleasure, [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/CecbP/).

Comment: what does display:block does?